# Error a crear Base de datos en Java: no existe la base de datos

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

intento crear y acceder a una base de datos en java,estoy usando la libreria postgresql-42.2.2 . 
Este es mi metodo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Connection c = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/BaseDatos",
                        "postgres", "1234");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

El error que me devuelve es este:

```
jun 05, 2018 5:43:10 PM org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl log
ADVERTENCIA: SQLException occurred while connecting to localhost:5432
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «BaseDatos» (pgjdbc: autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user, password, pg_hba.conf)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2433)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2566)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:131)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:210)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at creando.y.usando.bd.CreandoYUsandoBD.main(CreandoYUsandoBD.java:18)
```

Me podrían decir como solucionarlo?
Agradecería mucho su ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: No estas creando una  base de datos, estas accediendo a ella, no existe la base de datos  que especificas como "BaseDatos".

Comment: Verifica el nombre de tu base de datos, y además checa toda la ruta a tu servidor de base de datos, pues es posible que no encuentre la base de datos, porque la conexión no se ha realizado.

Comment: Si y ame di cuenta de ese error. No estaba creando la Base de Datos.

Comment: ahi no existe comando alguno para crear una base de datos

Answer (score 0):

Si y ame di cuenta de ese error. No estaba creando la Base de Datos. De esta forma ya estoy creándola.

```
public  void creandoBD(String[] args) {
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/",
                        "postgres", "1234");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE DATABASE Basedatos2";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

}

El asusto es que ahora me da error si la base de datos ya existe.

La pregunta seria: Como modificar este código para que cada vez que corra el programa antes de crear la base de datos ver si ya existe y solo sea conectar?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez `... IF NOT EXISTS` es propio de MySQL, en Postgresql no funciona. Para verificar debe enviar una consulta a [`pg_catalog.pg_database`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-database.html), algo así más o menos: **`SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE LOWER(datname) = LOWER('nombre-base-de-datos');`**  donde `nombre-base-de-datos` sería el nombre que quieres verificar. Si la consulta arroja datos significa que existe y si no arroja entonces se procedería a crearla.

Comment: Perfecto, la consulta: 
    SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE LOWER(datname) = LOWER('nombre-base-de-datos');

Comment: La consulta: 
    SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE LOWER(datname) = LOWER('nombre-base-de-datos');
me sirve para saber si existe o no la base de datos. El problema esta en que yo ejecuto la consulta desde java con jdbc.
Y para saber si existe la guardo en un ResultSet que luego le paso a un String. El problema esta en que si la consulta no devuelve resultados, a la hora de asignarle el resultado de la consulta al ResulSet, me da un NullPointerException. Como se podría modificar la consulta para que si no encuentra la base de datos devuelva algo que me lo sugiera?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de esta manera.

```
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Connection c = null;

    String selectSQL = "SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE LOWER(datname) = LOWER(?)";
    String nombreBD="Pon-aqui-el-nombre-de-la-bd";

    try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        c = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/BaseDatos",
                    "postgres", "1234");
        ps = c.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
        ps.setString(1, nombreBD);

        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        /*Verificar si encontró datos*/
        if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {    
            System.out.println("No existe BD, vamos a crearla"); 
            String createSQL = "CREATE DATABASE ?";
            ps = c.prepareStatement(createSQL);
            ps.setString(1, nombreBD);
            int filas = ps.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Se creó "+ filas +" base de datos"); 
        } 

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);

    /*Cerrar recursos*/
    } finally {

        if (ps != null) {
            ps.close();
        }

        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Lo siento amigo pero al ejecutarlo me sigue diciendo que la base de datos no existe. Lo ideal seria modificar la consulta 
    SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE LOWER(datname) = LOWER(BaseDatos);
 para que siempre me devuelva algo? Por ejemplo: verdadero si existe la base de datos y falso si no. Y luego solo comprobar. Gracias y saludos.